# Spring security works with access="ROLE_USER" but not with EL

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm learning to use Spring Security and I've integrated it in a web application. I'm using Spring and Spring Security version 3.1.2.

If I specify `access="ROLE_USER"` in the security configuration, the authentication, works correctly, that is I first receive a 401 and after logging in, I'm able to access the resources.

```
<http>
    <http-basic />
    <logout />
    <intercept-url
        pattern="/exports/**"
        access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>
```

However, if I switch to EL, my check doesn't work anymore:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <http-basic />
    <logout />
    <intercept-url
        pattern="/exports/**"
        access="hasRole('USER')" />
</http>
```

I thought that those two configuration were equivalent, but the second one is not authorising to view the resource (403 error).

Looking at the logs:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@844f42c6: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@c052d588: Username: test; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER

DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@1a15597, returned: -1

DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
```

If I understand right, the WebExpressionVoter is voting against me, despite the authentication worked.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple: just add `ROLE_` also in `hasRole()`, such as:

```
access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"
```

I got mislead by an example in section 16.2 of the [manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/el-access.html).

Comment: Hey, I know this is an old question, but in your research did you discover why this is required? why does it have to be preceded by "ROLE_"? Do all role names need this syntax?

Comment: "The use of the prefix ROLE_ is a marker to indicate that these attributes are roles and should be consumed by Spring Security's RoleVoter. This is only relevant when a voter-based AccessDecisionManager is in use. "

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/technical-overview.html